# Learning FPGA Design (Books, Resources, VHDL/Verilog)

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, xilinx, intel-fpga

I used to use FPGA's back in college and I really enjoyed it. Years have passed though and I haven't had much time to play with it since then. I have realized I have forgotten some stuff (quite a bit actually).

I am on the way to relearn FPGA design. I have a DE2-70 board which I dug up the other day. What I was looking for suggestions in is what HDL should I learn. I used VHDL before, but I have send Verilog being quite popular as well. Also, suggestions for resources/tutorials/books that people can guide me to would greatly help.

Also, I was thinking of designing a memory controller unit for an SSRAM. I have never done this before, so I don't really know all the complications involved with memory controller design.